# Placing Python libraries in zip file and shared libraries

Tags: python, php-ziparchive

I'm working on putting Python on a resource limited embedded system so I'm working on placing all of the pre-compiled (.pyc or pyo) python files in a zip archive.

I understand that only Python files (i.e. .py, .pyo and .pyc) files can go in the zip archive and for the most part things are working.

The problem is modules that have shared libraries as sub modules are having problems finding and loading the shared libraries.

A good example is the SqlAlchemy module. 
It has as three shared library sub-modules scprocessors.cpython-34m.so, cresultproxy.cpython-34m.so and cutils.cpython-34m.so.

If I place all of the Sqlalchemy Python files in python34.zip file and leave the .so files in their original locations I can import sqlalchemy but not any of the sub-modules.

I think the problem maybe that the importer locates the SqlAlchemy module in the zip file first and from then on expects to find all submodules in the same location and it never looks in the original location.

Is there anything I can do make this work?

Comment: What is this magic "importer"?  What does "having problems finding and loading" mean in this context?  We need a lot more background / system info to be able to help you.

Comment: By "importer" I mean the standard python import system.

Comment: The target system is python 3.4 on an embedded Linux ARM system, but I don't think that should matter.
By having problems I mean, if I launch the interpreter and attempt to import sqlalchemy.cprocessors like so I get the following error: 
  
    >>> from sqlalchemy import cprocessors
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name 'cprocessors'

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of an alternate implementation that might store everything that is static on a compressed read-only filesystem, squashfs-style?  Obviously there are different tradeoffs, and it would be out if you need to change these frequently at runtime, but semantics could be simpler.

Comment: It's already on a readonly ubifs file system with compression turned on.
UIBFS compression is pretty light, so adding the files to a zip archive really does reduce the size without impacting the speed.